# How to launch Firefox in Private Mode with NodeJS and Selenium?

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to launch Firefox in private mode with TypeScript.  I have tried this and it will not use private mode:

```
static async CreateFirefoxDriver():Promise<WebDriver>
{
    //Create the firefox capabilities
    var firefoxCapabilities = Capabilities.firefox();

    //Use Private Window
    var firefoxOptions = {
        'args': ['-private']};

    firefoxCapabilities.set('firefoxOptions', firefoxOptions);
    var driver = await new Builder().withCapabilities(firefoxCapabilities).build();

    //Maximize the window
    await driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to configure it correctly:

```
static async CreateFirefoxDriver():Promise<WebDriver>
{
    var options = new firefox.Options();
    options.addArguments("-private");

    var driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").setFirefoxOptions(options).build();

    //Maximize the window
    await driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
}
```